# Algebraic area of Brownian half-plane excursion

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, probability-distributions, brownian-motion

Is anything known about the **distribution of the algebraic area**, à la [Lévy's stochastic area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy%27s_stochastic_area), **of a Brownian excursion in the half-plane?** To be precise, letting $x>0$, we consider the path $(X_t,Y_t)_{t\in[0,1]}$ where $(X_t)_{t\in[0,1]}$ is a standard Brownian bridge from $X_0=x$ to $X_0=0$ and $(Y_t)_{t\in[0,1]}$ a standard Brownian excursion.

In the case $x=0$, this process is related via a Vervaat transform to the standard Brownian bridge in $\mathbb{R}^2$ preserving the algebraic area. So the algebraic area $S$ satisfies $\mathbb{E}[e^{ia S}]=\frac{a}{2\sinh(a/2)}$ by Lévy's original work (see the Wikipedia page linked above). I wonder whether this formula can be generalized to $x\neq 0$.

[image: Algebraic area of half-plane excursion]

Here's a simulation of such a Brownian excursion with $x=1$, with shading by winding number. The algebraic area would equal the sum of the shaded areas multiplied with their winding number (and suitable regularization).

**Update:** It is not too difficult to compute the moments of the area $S$ order by order, for instance by examining the scaling of the corresponding random walk problem. The first 6 moments are:

$$
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & \mathbb{E}[S^n] \\\hline
 1 &  x \sqrt{\frac{\pi }{8}}\\
 2 & \frac{1}{12} \left(5 x^2+1\right) \\
 3 & \frac{3}{64} \left(5 x^3+3x\right) \sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}}\\
 4 & \frac{1}{5040}\left(1105 x^4+1326 x^2+147\right) \\
 5 & \frac{5}{4096}\left(113 x^5+226 x^3+753\right)\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}}\\
 6 & \frac{1}{576576}\left(82825 x^6+248475 x^4+164493 x^2+13299\right) \\
\end{array}
$$
In particular, this suggests the $n$th moment is a polynomial of degree $n$ in $x$. **Does anyone recognize these polynomials?**